# Collisions not registering, but still affecting

Tags: collision-detection, freeze

I'm making a game with Corona in .lua, and i have one hell of a problem here.

The player tilts the iphone screen around to make a ball roll through a maze. Simple, right?

the ball bounces and collides fine off one wall, but on the others, the ball sticks. It stops dead.

the REAL problem became apparent when I tried to debug this first problem. No collisions were heard. Not by runtime, not by the individual object, nada. The ball stops and freezes when it hits the wall, but no collision events occur.

Does anyone have ANY idea why this would happen, and what to do?

I've all objects in the scene are now bullet. physics has been started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a while ago. I found that I was creating some objects inverted. Make sure you create the top left corner of your object first.